# what is the default scope in JSF 1.1?

Tags: jsf

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>beanName</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>BeanClasss</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Is it mandatory to specify the scope of a manage bean in JSF 1.1. If it it is not mandatory, then what is the default scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<managed-bean-scope>` entry is mandatory for the `faces-config.xml` to be parsed correctly. Omitting it would result in a XML parsing error. However, next to `request`, `session` and `application` JSF also supports a scope of [`none`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086896/what-is-none-scope-bean-and-when-to-use-it).