# Update primefaces panel from inside ui:component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When i click the 'Go to page 1 from included' (page2.xhtml) the centerPanel (index.xhtml) just go blank and my doNav method is not called as follows:

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="245">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:menu>
                            <p:submenu label="Resources">
                                <p:menuitem value="Page 1" actionListener="#{navBean.doNav}" update=":centerPanel">
                                    <f:param name="page" value="page1" />
                                </p:menuitem>
                                <p:menuitem value="Page 2" actionListener="#{navBean.doNav}" update=":centerPanel">
                                    <f:param name="page" value="page2" />
                                </p:menuitem>
                            </p:submenu>
                        </p:menu>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>


                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <p:panel id="centerPanel">
                        <c:if test="#{navBean.page != null}">
                            <ui:include src="#{navBean.page}.xhtml" />
                        </c:if>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:layoutUnit>


            </p:layout>
```

**page1.xhtml**

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

        Page 1

    </ui:composition>

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

**page2.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h3>Page 2</h3>

    <p:commandButton value="Go to page 1 from included" actionListener="#{navBean.doNav}" update=":centerPanel">
        <f:param name="page" value="page1" />
    </p:commandButton>

</ui:composition>
```

**NavBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "navBean")
public class NavBean {

    private String page = null;

    public void doNav() {
        this.page = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap().get("page");
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

}
```

Is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see is your NavBean is `@NoneScoped` because you have not specified a scope. `@NoneScoped` will cause a NavBean to be created every time you reference it from an expression, so your page variable has not been set when you use it. You need to specify a scope for your NavBean to be at least `@ViewScoped`. Read over these questions as well:

- [what is none scope bean and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086896/what-is-none-scope-bean-and-when-to-use-it)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)