# Multiple @ManagedProperty of same Type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a manged bean where I use another managed bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{tableActions}") 
private TableActions table1;
```

that works fine.

Now I need to use another instance of it:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{tableActions}") 
private TableActions table1;    

@ManagedProperty(value="#{tableActions}") 
private TableActions table2;
```

However, now `table2` is the same as `table1`. How can I create a separate instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `@NoneScoped` bean.

You only need to make sure you access it in view via `#{yourParentBean.table1}` and not via `#{tableActions}`.

#### See also:

- [what is none scope bean and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086896/what-is-none-scope-bean-and-when-to-use-it)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)